Taylor Approximation of Third Order
Problem:
Given the function $ f(x, y) = e^{x^2} \log(1 + x + y) $ near the point $ (0, 0) $, find the third-order Taylor approximation of the function at $ (0, 0) $ using known series and verify the coefficients by differentiation.
Attempt:
I'm familiar with the Taylor series for $ e^{x^2} $:
$$ e^{x^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k}}{k!}. $$
Because we are interested in $ T_3(x) $, I assume, that only the first two terms are necessary: $e^{x^2} = 1 + x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)$.
After differentiating $ \log(1+x+y) $, I found the third-degree Taylor polynomial to be:
$$ f(x,y) \approx (1+x^2) \left[(x+y) - \frac{(x+y)^2}{2} + \frac{(x+y)^3}{3}\right]. $$
However, I'm uncertain about how to arrive at this approximation using known series, and even if I did it correct. Can someone offer a hint?

Mathematica:  $\left(y-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{3}+O\left(y^4\right)\right)+x
\left(1-y+y^2-y^3+O\left(y^4\right)\right)+x^2 \left(-\frac{1}{2}+2 y-2 y^2+\frac{7
y^3}{3}+O\left(y^4\right)\right)+x^3 \left(\frac{4}{3}-2 y+3 y^2-\frac{13
y^3}{3}+O\left(y^4\right)\right)+O\left(x^4\right)$

The third degree polynomial at $(0,0)$ involves $x^ky^l$ where $k+l\le 3.$ There are  too many terms in your expansion. The correct result is $$(x+y)-{1\over 2}(x+y)^2+{1\over 3}(x+y)^3+x^2(x+y)$$

@DavidG.Stork. Have a look at  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/multivariable-taylor-expansion-does-not-work-as-expected .
Using the first answer, I obtained Ryszard Szwarc's result (which differs from your.
